# Converting relative paths into absolute ones not working in JSoup

Tags: java, html, jsoup

I'm trying to access relative links (a[href]) in a webpage and replacing them into absolute ones, and printing the modified HTML of the webpage on the console. But, when I'm looking at the links after having run the program, no changes have been made. Here's my code:

```
        Document doc = null;

    try {
        doc = Jsoup.connect("http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/dom-navigation").userAgent("Mozilla").get();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    Elements imports = doc.select("a[href]");
    String s = "";
    for (Element link : imports) {
        //System.out.println("\n"+link.attr("href"));
        //System.out.println(link.attr("abs:href"));

        if(link.attr("href").equalsIgnoreCase("/")){
            //Do nothing for now
        }
        else{
            s = doc.toString().replaceAll(link.attr("href"), link.attr("abs:href"));
        }
    }
    System.out.println(s);
```

One very strange thing is that, in this program, I'm connecting to http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/dom-navigation but when I connect to this link http://csb.stanford.edu/class/public/pages/sykes_webdesign/05_simple.html I notice that the changes are being made. So what could be the problem here, something wrong with my code or with the webpage?!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please try `<your element>.absUrl("href")` instead. And for testing, print your result **element** *directly* after you have changed it.

For replacing the urls you can use something like (*not* tested):

```
Elements urls = doc.select("a[href]");

for( Element urlElement : urls )
{
    urlElement.attr("href", urlElement.absUrl("href"));
    System.out.println(urlElement); // Print result directly after changes have been done
}
```

Comment: Hey, this works! Actually, I was just printing each element to see if the changes were made individually (and yes, they were made), but on printing the whole html doc no changes were made whatsoever, and it was the whole modified html doc that I needed. That was really strange. Anyways, the code that you've provided, specially the `urlElement.attr("href", urlElement.absUrl("href"));` line, works perfectly. Thank you.

Comment: That's strange, it seems you work on a copy and not the actual document somewhere. Just for testing, you can try *replacing* such a node instead of changing it value.